# Call multiple functions onClick ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know in vanilla JavaScript, we can do:

```
onclick="f1();f2()"
```

What would be the equivalent for making two function calls `onClick` in ReactJS?

I know calling one function is like this:

```
onClick={f1}
```

Comment: Very simple: pass a function that calls the two functions, just like you would to with `ele.onclick = ...` or `addEventListener`.

Comment: In case your 1st function is setState and you need to make sure this is happening/taken into account before the 2nd function runs, you will find this post quite helpful: https://medium.com/better-programming/when-to-use-callback-function-of-setstate-in-react-37fff67e5a6c

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Wrap your two+ function calls in another function/method. Here are a couple variants of that idea:

**1) Separate method**

```
var Test = React.createClass({
   onClick: function(event){
      func1();
      func2();
   },
   render: function(){
      return (
         <a href="#" onClick={this.onClick}>Test Link</a>
      );
   }
});
```

or with ES6 classes:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
   onClick(event) {
      func1();
      func2();
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <a href="#" onClick={this.onClick}>Test Link</a>
      );
   }
}
```

**2) Inline**

```
<a href="#" onClick={function(event){ func1(); func2()}}>Test Link</a>
```

or ES6 equivalent:

```
<a href="#" onClick={() => { func1(); func2();}}>Test Link</a>
```

Comment: Or less optimal: `onclick={function() { f1(); f2(); }}`

Comment: Or in ES6 `onclick={()=>{ f1(); f2() }}`

Comment: Or in cjsx: `onClick={ () => f1(); f2() }`

Comment: what if first one is asynchronous ..i want the second one to be executed only after the first one gets successfully completed

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai that's a whole other concern which is unrelated to React. It's all about async in JS and [`Promises` are probably the answer you were looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39458201/1218980)

Answer (score 31):

Maybe you can use arrow function (ES6+) or the simple old function declaration.

Normal function declaration type (**Not ES6+**):

```
<link href="#" onClick={function(event){ func1(event); func2();}}>Trigger here</link>
```

Anonymous function or arrow function type (**ES6+**)

```
<link href="#" onClick={(event) => { func1(event); func2();}}>Trigger here</link>
```

The second one is the shortest road that I know. Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 21):

React Functional components

```
             <button
                onClick={() => {
                  cancelOrder();
                  handlerModal();
                }}
             >
                Cancel
             </button>
```

Comment: Easiest option IMO

Answer (score 16):

Calling multiple functions on onClick for any element, you can create a wrapper function, something like this.

```
wrapperFunction = () => {
    //do something
    function 1();
    //do something
    function 2();
    //do something
    function 3();
}
```

These functions can be defined as a method on the parent class and then called from the wrapper function.

You may have the main element which will cause the onChange like this,

```
<a href='#' onClick={this.wrapperFunction}>Some Link</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

**Best Way:**

```js
onClick={ () => { f1(); f2();} }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have to apply two function on a button click at the same time, then we can simply add like this in React js.

```
<button onClick={()=> {fun1(); fun2()}}>Show more</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply wrapped it inside `[]`. This will worked as well in material UI button.

```
<Button onClick={(event) => [function1(), function2()]}>Click Me</Button>
```

[Click to see sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYMe9.png)

[Click to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB439.png)

Answer (score 2):

Let say you have a button and you want to execute two onClick events,
to show the hidden text and hide the button with just 1 click.

```
let a = 'invisible'
  let b = 'visible'
  const [show, setShow] = useState(a)
  const [buttonshow, setButtonShow] = useState(b)

<button onClick={() => {setButtonShow(a); setShow(b)}}>Read More</button>
<p>This text will show after you press the button Read more and Read
more will be hidden from the DOM
</p>
```

as you see, the anonymous function just returned two functions.

```
{setButtonShow(a); setShow(b)}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
//Don't do this way
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log('hello');
          console.log('world');
        }}>
        I'm a button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

//Do this way
function App() {

  function fun1() {
    console.log('hello');
  }

  function fun2() {
    console.log('world');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {fun1();fun2();}}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested.

There are tow function one is `openTab()` and another is `closeMobileMenue()`, Firstly we call `openTab()` and call another function inside `closeMobileMenue()`.

```
function openTab() {
    window.open('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drishya');
    closeMobileMenue()   //After open new tab, Nav Menue will close.  
}

onClick={openTab}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one-liner:

```
onClick={ () => f1() ||  f2() }
```