# react passing multiple functions to components and invoking onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-props

I'm passing a function to a component (which works btw, loads language translated product list as json) :

```
<a onClick={this.props.lang_zh} href="#">ZH</a></li>
```

I also have a translation function (which works, translates all other content e.g. UI, text elements). This is a child component btw, i18n-react:

```
<a onClick={() => changeLanguage('zh')} href="#">ZH</a>
```

I need them both to load, but when I combine them onClick the passed props are not being received.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs) answer addresses multiple functions but neither separate method, inline arrow functions are working with combination of function and props (which  type is function btw not string). Any info/feeback appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried like this inside a block. it should work
 `onClick={() => {changeLanguage('zh'); this.props.lang_zh;}}`

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? The answers I've seen are causing an error "Expected an assignment or function call but instead saw an expression."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onclick={()=>{ this.props.lang_zh(); changeLanguage('zh'); }}
```

How about this?

Comment: Expected an assignment or function call but instead saw an expression