# Caling functions consecutively for one click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I need to execute 2 functions based on one onClick event. for this, I found some methods Via stackoverflow. (Referred [Call multiple functions onClick ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs/26069299))

But, in my case if I specified as `onClick={this.handleClick}` works as expected. But if I specified as `onClick={(event) => {this.handleClick()}}`, when clicking on button nothing happens. What could be the reason for this?
What is the optimal way of calling two functions one by one on one onClick where second function call depends on the result of first function call.

Comment: can you show full code? also that result is of some calculation or some api call result?

Comment: @MayankShukla this.handleClick calls an api which provides info related to authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

Your `onClick` goes like this which by default sends an event

```
onClick={this.handleClick}
```

handleClick event

```
handleClick = (event) => {
  fetch.fetchUrl(url [, options], ()=> {
   this.getFoo();
  })
}
getFoo = ()=>{}
```

**Second way**

You can send event by binding the function

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, additionalParameter)}
```

now click function would look like

```
handleClick = (additionParameter, event) =>{}
```

Additionally, If you would like to send additional parameters alongside you can go with the second way. Both the ways would still pass events attached with your handler.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, `this` is not defined statically for a piece of code (like in 99% other languages), but rather taken from the calling context (i.e. it is dynamically scoped), so it can differ depending on who calls the function and when.

In the second case, `this` evaluates late: when the function is called. In the first case, it is evaluated when the event is attached (so it is "correct").

The solution is simply to use the first version - there is nothing you gain by calling it late (the event will be passed anyway, as the first argument).

Answer (score 0):

Calling first function inside second should work. PFB the steps -

1. Define first function.
2. In second function definition, fist call first function and use the first function output accordingly for further operation statement in second function's definition.
3. call second function on click event.

This will lead to call second function but will do operation on the basis of the output provided on calling first function.