# multiple functions onClick not working reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call two multiple functions onClick.It doesn't work when i try to do it.But it works in single function.these are the two functions.

```
   //first function
saveValue = (e) => {
    // console.log('savecategory', e.target.innerHTML);

    this.setState({
        category: e.target.innerHTML
    }, this.makeAxiosRequest);

};

//second function

goToLastPage = () => {
    const {currentPage, pages, end} = this.state;
};
```

This is the onClick event i am trying to work.

```
<button   onclick={()=>{this.saveValue();this.goToLastPage()}}>Residence</button>
```

But it doesn't work.It only works if i call it as a single function like this.

```
<button onClick={this.saveValue}>Residence</button>

<button onClick={this.goToLastPage}>Residence</button>
```

How can i make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call multiple functions onClick ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs)

Comment: It would be nice if you expanded on "it doesn't work" do you get an error? are your functions called at all?

Comment: i don't get any error.this functions do not execute i call multiple functions.

Answer (score 1):

`saveValue` function needs event argument. So try this:

```
<button onClick={(e) => { this.saveValue(e); this.goToLastPage(); }}>Residence</button>
```

Also, instead `onclick` should be `onClick`

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your first example you typed `onclick` instead of `onClick`. Notice the capitalization of `C`. React event handlers are camel-cased.

Comment: I did that part right on my code.sorry for that unwanted error here.The problem was with event argument. First reply answers my questions.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use onClick instead of onclick. This is a difference in HTML and Reactjs.

For more details follow this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Also check this out: [Call multiple functions onClick ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
<button onClick={()=>{this.saveValue();this.goToLastPage()}}>Residence</button>
```