# How to call multiple function on one click in react

Tags: reactjs

Just want to call to function on one click in react js

```
handleProjectSelection = (v1, v2) => () => {
    console.log(`${v1} and ${v2}`)
}
anotherfunctionCall = (ss) => () => {
    console.log(ss) 
}
```

```
<p onClick={() => { this.handleProjectSelection("sdsdsd", 'dksdsd'); this.anotherfunctionCall("second");}}> click event </p>
```

if there are two function with double arrow then i want to call both on one click in react

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - can you briefly describe the problem or error(s) you're getting with the code in your question?

Comment: Duplicate of [Call multiple functions onClick ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs)

Comment: The arrow function handler you have mentioned will also work. Basically, your click handler is referencing to a function which internally calls two functions. This is correct.

Comment: Hi,if i use single arrow for both of function then it's working but not for double arrow in react js.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use only `one` arrow function to call in `onClick`event.

```
handleProjectSelection = (v1, v2) => {
    console.log(`${v1} and ${v2}`)
}
anotherfunctionCall = (ss) => {
    console.log(ss) 
}
<p onClick={() => { this.handleProjectSelection("sdsdsd", 'dksdsd'); this.anotherfunctionCall("second");}}> click event </p>
```

Comment: it's working for single arrow but in single arrow we can't use function as a props in react.

Answer (score 0):

```
 handleOnClick = (v1,v2,ss) {
   handleProjectSelection(v1,v2);
   anotherfunctionCall(ss);
}

<p onClick={() =>{ this.handleOnClick("sdsdsd", 'dksdsd',"second")> click event </p>
```