# How do I have 2 onClick action on javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm kind of confused,

I need to have two actions when onClick this {this.startTextHandler} and an alert when click

```
<Form.Item>
  {/* <button onClick={this.startTextHandler} className="psButton">START THE TEST</button> */}
  <Button onClick={this.startTextHandler} text="START THE TEST" />
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Just call `alert('some text')` inside your `startTextHandler`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call multiple functions onClick ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that includes both events:

```
<Button onClick={this.callTwoFuncs} text="START THE TEST" />

<script>
function callTwoFuncs() {
    this.startTextHandler();
    this.sendAlert();
}
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write one function that does two things.

```
startTextHandler(e) {
    // etc
},
doSomethingElse(e) {
    // etc
},
startTextHandlerAndDoSomethingElse(e) {
    this.startTextHandler(e);
    this.doSomethingElse(e);
}

....

onClick={this.startTextHandlerAndDoSomethingElse}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button onClick={()=> { this.startTextHandler(); this.secondAction(); } } text="START THE TEST" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an **anonomus function**:

```
<Button 
    onClick={(event) => {
        this.startTextHandler(event);
        this.secondMethod(eventOrWhatever)
    }} 
    text="START THE TEST" 
/>
```

or a **named function**:

```
<Button 
    onClick={this.handleClick} 
    text="START THE TEST" 
/>

handleClick = (event) => {
    this.startTextHandler(event);
    this.secondMethod(eventOrWhatever);
}
```

BTW: named function give you a better stacktrace too when debugging

Comment: Generating a function inside the render handler can cause performance problems and is best avoided. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render

Comment: True that, but as long as you do not use the button in each row of a list with >100 entries you should be fine though. Even the linked doc says it's OK as long as you don't get performance issues: 'Generally speaking, yes, it is OK, and it is often the easiest way to pass parameters to callback functions.'