# Call two functions with onPress in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following two buttons:

```
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button title="ADD" onPress={createDocumentHandler}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button title="CANCEL" color="red" onPress={props.onCancel}/>
        </View>
```

I want the first button to trigger both the "createDocumentHandler" function and the "props.onCancel" function

I thought it would be as easy as `onPress={createDocumentHandler, props.onCancel}` but that only triggers the second method for some reason

Comment: Why don't you just make a function, that calls both, and call that with the button?

Comment: Because anytime I tried to do that {props.onCancel} would never be called

Comment: `onPress={() => { createDocumentHandler(); props.onCancel(); }}` (also: what you tried didn't work because `a, b` evaluates to `b`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call multiple functions onClick ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs)

Comment: @ChrisG unsure if there are arguments or `this` context, so potentially `function (...args) { createDocumentHandler.call(this, ...args); props.onCancel.call(this, ...args); }`, but maybe it's certain, that there are just none.

Comment: @ASDFGerte True, this should do it: `onPress={e => { createDocumentHandler(e); props.onCancel(e); }}` (99% sure it's a functional comp)

Comment: To be reasonable, OP should know, whether it's necessary, because the related functions are his, and it's therefore obvious, whether they use `this` or any arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Button title="ADD" onPress={createDocumentHandler}/>
createDocumentHandler = () => {
   actionA();
   actionB();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a custome function createDocumentHandler as :

```
createDocumentHandler = async() => {
// execute in whatever order
  let a =  await function1();
  let b =  await function2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onCancel() => {
    {...}
 };
 function createDocumentHandler()
 {
     {...}
     return onCancel();
 }

function render(){
    return(
        <Button title="ADD" onPress={createDocumentHandler}/>
    )
}
```