# Calling two functions with onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to call two functions immediately one after another when user clicks a button, but I am not able to do so.

In the first function, I am calling `handleChange()` method in which it sets the status value using `status: event.target.value`

And in the second function, it should execute `onSubmit()` method in which I am updating the status value in DB which previously `handleChange()` method sets.

Here is my code snippet:

```js
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, error: false, status: event.target.value });
};
    
console.log(status);    

const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValues({ status:"", error: false, loading: true });
    console.log(status);
    updateOrderStatus(match.params.orderId, user._id, token, status).then(
      (data) => {
        if (data.error) {
          setValues({  error: data.error, success: false });
        } else {
          setValues({  status: "", success: true });
          console.log("STATUS:",status);
        }
      }
    )};

    const createOrderForm = () => {
      return (
        <button
            type="submit"
            onClick={handleChange,onSubmit}
            value="Cancelled"
            className={
              status === "Cancelled"
                ? "btn btn-primary mr-3"
                : "btn btn-outline-success mr-3"
            }
          >
            Cancelled
      )
```

Here are my screenshot and log files for what exactly I am trying for:

[Initially](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhDtA.png)
[After clicking on the Cancelled button it should change the status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqemF.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call multiple functions onClick ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` expects a function, when you give two functions seperated by comma, it only takes the first one. Instead you give a function and execute two functions inside it.
this will work

`onClick={()=>{handleChange();onSubmit()}}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to make a higher order function that calls the two subsequent functions:

```
onClick={(event) => {
    handleChange(event)
    onSubmit(event)
}}
```

Or you could just call `handleChange` from inside `onSubmit`:

```
const onSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
handleChange(event)
setValues({ status:"", error: false, loading: true });
console.log(status);
updateOrderStatus(match.params.orderId, user._id, token, status).then(
  (data) => {
    if (data.error) {
      setValues({  error: data.error, success: false });
    } else {
      setValues({  status: "", success: true });
      console.log("STATUS:",status);
    }
  }
)};
```

In this case you can just call `onClick` from your components click event:

```
onClick={onSubmit}
```

Also note that in your `.then` callback, you are calling to `setValues` here:

```
    setValues({  status: "", success: true });
    console.log("STATUS:",status);
```

When `setValues` is called, it will cause a re-render of the component.  On that re-render, the `status` pulled out of `values` will reflect the empty string you added here: `setValues({  status: "", success: true });`.

However, the `status` in `console.log("STATUS:",status)` will reflect the value of `status` before the re-render, that being `"pending"`.

Comment: I tried this but it does not get the output I want...my status and values are coming from const [values, setValues] = useState({
    error: "",
    status: "",
    success: false,
  });
 const { status, error, success } = values;

Comment: my backend api call is :                                                                                                        export const updateOrderStatus = (orderId, userId, token, status) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/order/${orderId}/status/${userId}`, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(status),
    
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

Comment: Updated my answer to address things further.  Please take a look.

Comment: Can you suggest me what should I do ?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do.  It seems like you're trying to get some part of the response (your `data` argument) into `setValues`.  Perhaps you mean to add `setValues({  status: "completed", success: true, value: data });` inside of your `else` statement in the callback.