# How to call two arrow functions onclick ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen a lot of threads about calling multiple traditionally declared functions in React onclick, but I'm confused how I could implement that with arrow functions. I have a function called handleClose, which closes a Material UI menu:

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const anchorRef = React.useRef(null);
const handleClose = (event) => {
    if (anchorRef.current && anchorRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  };
```

And I have a function called handleModalOpen, which open a Material UI Modal:

```
const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = React.useState(false);
const handleModalOpen = () => {
  setModalOpen(true);
};
```

When I click this menu item, I would like both functions to run. Both functions individually work fine on their own. So how would I achieve this? (Currently I only have it set so the modal opens)

```
<MenuItem onClick={handleModalOpen}>Add Album</MenuItem>
```

Basically I have a button that triggers a menu, and then clicking one of those menu options should trigger a modal whilst closing the menu. Also, this is a functional component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call multiple functions onClick ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you can create an inline arrow function which calls the both

```
<MenuItem onClick={(e) => {handleModalOpen(); handleClose(e); }}>Add Album</MenuItem>
```

Or you can create a function outside and pass its reference

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  handleModalOpen(); 
  handleClose(e);
}

<MenuItem onClick={handleClick}>Add Album</MenuItem>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error because event isn't being passed for handleClose.

Comment: You just need to pass an argument, I've updated the answer.