# how do Two different functions on a single onclick in reactjs Toggle button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have two different function

```
Deactivate = () => {
 //logic for deactivate
}

Activate = () => {
 //logic for activate
}


   return (
       <div>
          <Toggle
              defaultChecked={this.state.isChecked}
              className="switch-danger"
            />
       </div>
     )
```

first time click on toggle button when trigger the 'Deactivate function', then second time click  trigger 'Activate button'.

Comment: did you visit? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs

Comment: `onClick={() => this.state.isChecked ? this.Deactivate() : this.Activate()}`

Comment: Do you hold the "activated" value in state to use a simple ternary in a callback handler? Would this be something better suited to a lifecycle function? Can you update your question to include complete code and what, if any, issues you have with what you're trying to do?

Comment: @DennisVash Not a dupe of that; OP is looking to call either A or B, not both at the same time.

Comment: @ChrisG so the dupe with an if on state...

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah, I guess the method of creating a separate function is close enough; just not sure it's obvious for everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly make `Toggle` as a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and then if `isChecked` is `true` call `Activate` and `false` for `Deactivate` or vice-versa.

```
...
checkHandler = () => {
  this.setState((previousState) => {
    const isChecked = !previousState.isChecked

    isChecked ? this.activate() : this.deactivate()

    return { isChecked }
  })
}

deactivate = () => {
  //logic for deactivate
}

activate = () => {
  //logic for activate
}

render() {
  const { isChecked } = this.state

  return (
    <div>
      <Toggle
        className="switch-danger"
        value={isChecked}
        onChange={this.checkHandler}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: please describe me using code

Comment: @benzene check my edit