# How to handle two functions onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my Class component `App.jsx` I have the following function:

```
import { Position } from "./Position";
...

getPositionData = val => {
    const { players } = this.props;       
    var res = players.filter(o=>Object.values(o).includes(val))        
    return res
  };
```

Which is being handled at `render()` when I click on a subcomponent inside a `<div>`, like so:

```
<div className="field-row"> 
   {this.getPlayersByPosition(players, 4).map((player,i) => (
      <Position key={i} handleClick={this.getPositionData}>{player.name}</Position>
    ))} 
</div>
```

---

On its turn, `Position.jsx` handles `onClick()`:

```
export const Position = props => (
  <div
    className={`position-wrapper ${
      isManager(props.children) ? null : "field"
    }`}
    onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.children)}
  >
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
```

---

But now I'd like to handle a second function when `<div>` is clicked, say:

```
 toggleFullScreen() {
    this.setState({ fullScreen: !this.state.fullScreen });
  }
```

which I would pass, on its own, like so:

```
onClick={this.toggleFullScreen.bind(this)}
```

---

How do I handle BOTH functions `onClick()` at once in

```
<div className="field-row"> 
...
</div>
```

?

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like you can invoke multiple functions at once in a JS listener with

```
element.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fn1();
  fn2();
});
```

You can do the same thing in React by defining the `onClick` to be a function which invokes both:

```
<Position
  key={i}
  getPositionData={this.getPositionData}
  toggleFullScreen={toggleFullScreen}
>{player.name}</Position>
```

```
export const Position = props => (
  <div
    className={`position-wrapper ${
      isManager(props.children) ? null : "field"
    }`}
    onClick={() => {
      props.getPositionData(props.children);
      props.toggleFullScreen();
    }}
  >
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
```